# Order orthogonal polygon python

Tags: python, polygon, computational-geometry

How can  I order a list of orthogonal polygon points?

For example, I have a list of orthorgonal polygon points

```
data = [(2, 0), (5, 0), (5, 7), (4, 7), (4, 5), (3, 5),(3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 7), (2, 7)]
```

Not in order. 
I want to order it in a counter-clockwise way like this:

```
out = [(2,0),(5,0),(5,7),(4,7),(4,5),(3,5),(3,7),(2,7),(2,3),(3,3),(3,2),(2,2)]
```

I had tried to use `deflate _hull` already but it did not correct.
Is there any algorithm to solve this problem ?

I get this:

[image]

But expected :

[image]

Comment: How do you decide which point is the starting point? Is it the first point in any given list?

Comment: the first point will be the bottom left point,

Comment: this seems underdefined: `(4, 5), (3, 5), (3, 7)` is a right turn where `(3, 3)` was available for a left turn... `(3, 5), (3, 7), (2, 7)` is a left turn where `(3, 3)` was available as a U-turn, and closer... `(2, 7), (2, 3), (3, 3)` ia a L-turn where `(2, 2)` was available as Forward, and closer. Please clarify the rules of the hull you want to find.

Comment: If there is a point at `(1, 1)`, and a point at `(2, 0)`, and no points westwards of `x=1` or southwards of `y=0`, which one is the bottom left point?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque That is not a set of orthogonal polygon points.

Comment: oh, I see, sorry, I did not realize that orthogonal polygon was a well defined entity, thank you @blhsing - reading about it now.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, it no maters what is the first point, we can start at any point in the set. I think the hull is only applied to a convex polygon.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, we can see that (2,0), the next point is (5,0) have the same y value, and then the next point (5,7) have the same x, the next is (4,7) have the same y with the previous point, but I don't know the rule to choose the next point if we have many points which are  same x or y. That is my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following recursive function:

```
def sort_ortho_poly(points, current=None, start=None, go_x=True):
    # initialize the starting point at the bottom left, which should have the least sum of x and y
    if not current:
        start = current = min(points, key=sum)
    # if we're going x-wards, v would be the y index (1), h would be the x index (0), and vice versa 
    v, h = go_x, not go_x
    # remove the current point from the list of points so the next recursion would be processing the remaining points
    remaining = points[:]
    remaining.remove(current)
    # if there is no more remaining point
    if not remaining:
        # we've found a path if we are able to connect back to the starting point, or else we don't
        return [current] if start[v] == current[v] else []
    # try each point in the remaining points that goes in the right direction from the current point
    for next in [p for p in remaining if p[v] == current[v]]:
        # recursively find a valid path from the remaining points after flipping the direction
        path = sort_ortho_poly(remaining, next, start, not go_x)
        # if we get a path that does go back to the starting point, we have to make sure the path is valid
        if path:
            # the current edge (e1, e2)
            e1, e2 = current, next
            # make sure e1 is lower than or left of e2
            if e1[h] > e2[h]:
                e1, e2 = e2, e1
            # for each edge (p1, p2) in the path, including the final edge connecting to the starting point
            for p1, p2 in zip(path, path[1:] + [start]):
                # make sure p1 is lower than or left of p2
                if p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[1] > p2[1] or p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[0] > p2[0]:
                    p1, p2 = p2, p1
                # if the edge is in the same line as the current edge
                if p1[v] == p2[v] == e1[v]:
                    # make sure the two edges don't overlap
                    if e1[h] < p1[h] < e2[h] or e1[h] < p2[h] < e2[h] or p1[h] < e1[h] < p2[h] or p1[h] < e2[h] < p2[h]:
                        break
                # if the edge is perpendicular to the current edge, make sure they don't cross over
                elif p1[h] == p2[h] and e1[h] < p1[h] < e2[h] and p1[v] < e1[v] < p2[v]:
                    break
            else:
                # the path is valid! we append the path to the current point and return
                return [current, *path]
    # return empty if it's a dead end
    return []
```

so that:

```
data = [(2, 0), (5, 0), (5, 7), (4, 7), (4, 5), (3, 5),(3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 7), (2, 7)]
print(sort_ortho_poly(data))
```

would output:

```
[(2, 0), (5, 0), (5, 7), (4, 7), (4, 5), (3, 5), (3, 7), (2, 7), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank You for your help, I will read in carefully to understand and try more test case.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you find any issues. You can mark this answer as accepted if you do find it to be correct.

Comment: I'm new in python and stack also, so it will take me more time than usual to clearly understand your shorten code.  I will mark it if pass all my test cases. Thanks a lot for the comment in the code.

Comment: # make sure p1 is lower than or left of p2
                if p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[1] > p2[1] or p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[0] > p2[1]:

p1[0]> p2[1] concern me : I think it must be p1[0] > p2[0]: Can you explain me about it

Comment: Good catch! That was certainly a typo. Thanks for carefully reviewing my code! I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: can I ask you, which type of problem we can apply recursion? When I first solve this, I don't think that recursion will help

Comment: can I ask you, which type of problem we can apply recursion? When I first solve this, I don't think that recursion will help. Can I connect with you on any social media to inbox some question?

Comment: Any problem that can be defined with a procedure that consists of at least one step that invokes the procedure itself is by definition recursive. If a problem has a base case (in this case, a valid path that connects back to the starting point) and has a set of rules able to reduce all the other cases to a problem of the same type but closer the base case (in this case, we try one of the potentially viable next points and use the same rules to process the remaining points to get closer to connecting to the starting point).

Comment: I believe in the power of community though. Please feel free to post more questions on SO if you're ever stuck on anything. I as well as many other will be glad to help.

Comment: data = [[2, 0], [5, 7], [5, 0], [2, 7], [2, 2], [3, 3],
        [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 7], [4, 5], [3, 7]]   
i found that if i change the position of  [2,2] with [2,3]  like data above, this function not correct, because in the "return [current] if start[v] == current[v] else []" command you don't have rule for current [h]. It can be solve to add condition current[h] is minimum.

Comment: I want to add this 
a = min([k[1] for k in points if k[0] = start[0]])
and using it to compare with current[h], but this recursively functions
so I can not add command above to the code because Points will be [ ].So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Great test case! This is not due to the `return [current] if start[v] == current[v] else []` statement, however. This is because the list of edges derived from the returning path that I used to validate the path did not include the final edge that connects to the starting point. So instead of `for p1, p2 in zip(path, path[1:]):`, I've now corrected it to `for p1, p2 in zip(path, path[1:] + [start]):` so that even the last edge can be validated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `a = min([k[1] for k in points if k[0] = start[0]])`. I know it's the vertically closest point to the starting point, but what are you trying to do with it? Also, it should be a `==`, not `=`, between `k[0]` and `start[0]`.

Comment: Yes, but " for p1, p2 in zip(path, path[1:] + [start]):" is better Thanks for the enthusiastic help!

Comment: No problem. I now see what you were trying to do with the vertically closest point to the starting point, which is always guaranteed to be the last point in the path. Good thinking there, but yeah, it wouldn't be as generic a solution as including the last edge for validation.